# unity3d everyplay game video lightning is weird - black and white with lightening

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, everyplay

Watch this video - https://everyplay.com/videos/5747068

This video has all lightning messed up. I am not able to repro the problem on my own device. I do not have any information about the device which has posted the video. All other posted videos are working as expected - https://everyplay.com/war-of-worlds

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the video codecs on that device are not functioning properly and their colorspace configuration is messed up. The video in question seems to be made with a Sony Xperia SO-04E device, so we'll have to look into what that device has when it comes to codecs.

Comment: Thanks, make sense. Where do I see the device information associated with the video?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't at this point available through any interface, as I work for Everyplay I get "special access".